# QGIS - win32api

Tags: qgis, windows, pyqt5

I would like to send a docx file to a printer. So, with the win32api, "normally" it should works (QGIS 3.10).
In a python plugin, i try to import the win32api

```
import win32api

ImportError: DLL load failed The specified module could not be found
```

I've tried in python console, same result. I've tried in python console to get all available modules with `help('module')`, this time i have a new error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last): The specified file could not be found
  File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis-ltr/./python\console\console_sci.py", line 435, in keyPressEvent
    self.entered()
  File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis-ltr/./python\console\console_sci.py", line 603, in entered
    self.runCommand(self.currentCommand())
  File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis-ltr/./python\console\console_sci.py", line 616, in runCommand
    import webbrowser
  File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis-ltr/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 784, in _import
    _import_paths[p] = _AddDllDirectory(p)
  File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis-ltr/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 731, in _errcheck_zero
    raise ctypes.WinError(ctypes.get_last_error())
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2]
```

Impossible to render directly to a printer my docx file :(

Comment: I don't see the relation to GIS - could you elaborate?

Comment: @Erik : I wrote a plugin for QGIS which generates a Word file.

Comment: Can you provide a minimum example?

Comment: @Erik It's easy to reproduce, `import win32api` always failed. But, the module seems to be avalaible because `help('module')` appears well.

Comment: Why are your requesting the help for a module named 'module'?
Anyway, are you sure the package python3-pywin32 is installed in your QGIS Python installation?

Comment: @AndreaGiudiceandrea `help('modules')` display all avalaible modules, so i can confirm that pywin32 is well installed. (version 224)